# When are CSS and JS assets re-retrieved when using TurboLinks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS between each page change, TurboLinks keeps the current page instance alive and replaces only the body and the title in the head.

So, *when* do the JavaScript and CSS get reloaded and recompiled?

If I have users using my Rails app continuously for hours on end, is there any point the assets will be reloaded? What if I *need* them to be... i.e. I need to deploy a fix etc?

I know it's possible to [track certain assets](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#asset-change-detection) using `data-turbolinks-track` attribute, however I'm trying to understand from an *overall* perspective without depending on that.

Comment: Can someone please explain why I'm being down-voted for this question?

Comment: Because you should have searched this answer in Google instead of asking here :P

Comment: What the.... I've been searching for hours.. reading everything I can find. I'm asking here, because I can't find the answer. Isn't that what stackoverflow's for?

Comment: Yes it is. But not everyone thinks it's the right place to ask these questions :P

Answer (score 2):

Everyone gets downvoted some time - to ensure it doesn't happen, before you ask here, you really need to look at the docs & try to understand the problem as specifically as possible.

---

[**Turbolinks**](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks)

It's my understanding that Turbolinks evaluates your page on which files it needs to load in the `<head>` tag. If it finds the `<head>` tag is the same - it will just partially reload your page; whereas if you request different `<head>` files completely, Turbolinks will just refresh the page.

If you take the typical use case of Rails (having `application.css` and `application.js`), if you load 100 pages on this site, you'll end up having to provide these files 100 times.

Turbolinks uses Ajax to pull the `<body>` & `<title>` tags of the page you wish to load, leaving the `<head>` intact *if* it's meant to remain the same. This has nothing to do with Rails itself - it's just a JS addo-on which is meant to speed up the serving of pages

---

**Asset Compilation**

When you run a Rails application, there are two choices to how you serve the assets - *dynamically* or *statically*.

The static serving of assets is typical for [`production`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production) environments, whereby you'll have standard `.css` and `.js` files loaded with your page.

Turbolinks will reload these files if the user clicks onto a page which requires them to be reloaded. In contrast to `Sampriti Panda`'s suggestion that Turbolinks monitors the files in the backend is incorrect - it's only there to manage the user's use of the site

This means that regardless of whether you use asset [fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) (which is what you get from static asset [precompilation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)), or not, Turbolinks will still work in the same way (as described above)

---

**JS**

Bottom line is that Turbolinks is javascript

It has no bearing on the "backend" workings of Rails - so whether your files are static or dynamic doesn't matter. It's only dependent on how the user browses your application

It just takes any link on your page, evaluates the next page you wish to load, and determines whether it should reload the page as a whole, or just the `<body>` & `<title>` tags

Answer (score 1):

When Rails compiles assets on production, it inserts an MD5 fingerprint into each filename so that the file is cached by the web browser. When you change this file and redeploy, the fingerprint changes because the contents of the file change.

So the next time Turbolinks fetches a page, it is going to see a new asset file and is going to replace the current one with the newer version reloading the asset files.

Comment: Turbolinks isn't dependent on the filename - it's dependent on the content of the page predominently

Comment: When the file changes, the fingerprint changes and so the filename in the stylesheet/js include tag will change.

Comment: Yep but that's not turbolinks - that's Rails. The file changes don't have any bearing on Turbolinks directly

Comment: What I meant was, if the filename changes the content of the page in the include tag will also change.

Comment: Is the MD5 fingerprint what's talked about in the [Turbolinks readme](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#asset-change-detection)? From what I can tell, I have to specifically "turn this on" for certain assets. It's not a general "change detection". Is that right?